# Use javascript to center anchor object when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, anchor, onload

I want to jump to an anchor tag when my page loads AND have the anchor object centered in the window. I've used a simple function to go to the anchor when the page loads:

```
<body onload="goToAnchor();">

<script type="text/javascript">

function goToAnchor() {
window.location = "#center";
}

</script>
```

But in order for the anchor object to be centered, I need to somehow offset the location of the window. For another function, I used something like this to achieve the appropriate offset (the width of the object is a fixed 1500px):

```
var $offset_target = (1500 - $(window).width())/2;
```

This successfully ensured that each time I jumped to an anchor, the object was centered in the viewport, regardless of the window size.

Any ideas?

Thanks!!

**UPDATE/ANSWER**

So, I used two of the replies below to come up with this:

```
function goToAnchor() {
document.body.scrollLeft = document.documentElement.scrollLeft =       
document.getElementById('center').offsetLeft-
(Math.ceil((- 1500 + $(window).width()) / 2));
```

}

It might not be the most elegant solution, but it gets the job done! Thanks so much for your answers!

If anyone has a better way to do this, please let us know!

Comment: What part do you need help with?

Comment: Don't use script at all, use CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without jQuery:

```
function goToAnchor() {
    document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop =
        document.getElementById('center').offsetTop-window.innerHeight/2;
}
```

This will work fine in most cases. If `#center` is located in an element with `position` other than `static` then it would need a bit extra to calculate the correct offset, but otherwise it'll work as is.

Comment: The window still loads to the anchor, but the offset doesn't seem to have any effect. I used `offsetLeft-window.innerWidth/2`

Answer (score 0):

I did this for a website not too long ago, the code below uses the users window width and subtracts it from your static object's width, divides by two and scrolls horizontally to that location which will center the object horizontally.

```
$(window).scrollLeft(Math.ceil((1500 - $(window).width()) / 2));
```

Comment: This looks right, but where do I include this in the code? Does it have to go after some sort of `goToAnchor` function?

Comment: Like  

`function goToAnchor() {   
 window.location = "#center";  
 $(window).scrollLeft(Math.ceil((1500 - $(window).width()) /   2));`  

(that didn't work)

Comment: When I used this code I ran it inside the anonymous function of `document.ready`. Like so: `$(document).ready(function () {/*Code Here*/});`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need script at all, use CSS:

```
.centered {
  text-align: left;
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

IE needs to be in standards mode for this to work (which just means using a valid DOCTYPE). Setting both margins to auto makes them have the same value.

Here's a full example that centers the body element:

```
<style type="text/css">
.centered {
  text-align: left;
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.panel1 {border: 1px solid red;height: 200px}
.panel2 {border: 1px solid green;height: 200px}
</style>

<body class="centered">
  <div class="panel1">
    <div class="panel2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel1">
    <div class="panel2"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Well, what I'm making is basically a huge horizontal scrolling site, with a bunch of big "panels". I want the page to load to the center panel, but need it to be centered.  I don't think the css will work in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the help, though! I really appreciate all of the answers I received on this!

Comment: Why do you think it won't work? I've added an example to center the body. There is absolutely no reason to use script to do something that every browser in use can do natively using CSS.